# Rigify Traceback Error

Tags: python, add-on, error, rigify

When trying to enable the Rigify Addon, I'm met with this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\3.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 387, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\rigify\__init__.py", line 500, in register
    ui.register()
  File "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\rigify\ui.py", line 1418, in register
    animation_register()
  File "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\rigify\utils\animation.py", line 956, in register
    register_class(RIGIFY_OT_get_frame_range)
ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass 'RIGIFY_OT_get_frame_range'
```

I'm not knowledgable in this area whatsoever. This is a super basic addon and for some reason it's not functioning properly...

Comment: The message is telling you that some part of rigify was partially activated before you tried to enable rigify.  For a 3rd party add-on I'd tell you to remove the add-on and reinstall it but rigify is a built in and I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for putting that in laymen's terms for me. Not sure how part of it could already be installed, but yeah, the tricky thing is that it's already built in Blender...

Comment: I've seen it happen when you open a blend file that has a rigified armature and then save it as the factory default, but even then it was pretty rare and related to a timing error.  You can try opening the scripting window and typing bpy.unregister_class(RIGIFY_OT_get_frame_range)  You may have to repeat this several times, once for each error that mentions 'register_class', before you can finally make it work.

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve it. I reverted back to 3.0 from 3.1 and it's working again.

Comment: Sounds like a 3.1 bug but a weird one. I do have 3.1 downloaded an rigify enables fine for me.  At a long shot, can you add an empty 3.1 file to your question?  Maybe I can see what's going on. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))